# Why won't my javascript function execute when it's called?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a regular expression to check if the characters in the text box are only letters and hyphens, but for some reason when I call the function from onclick it will not execute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkChar() {
    var validLetters = /^[A-Z]+[-]*[A-Za-z]/;
    var element = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var fname = element.value;

    if (fname.match(/^[A-Z]+[-]*[A-Za-z]/) {
        window.alert("correct");
    } else {
        window.alert("incorrect");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type ="text" name ="firstName"/>
<button onclick="checkChar()">submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console in your browser's developer tools. The error message tells you what the problem is. (Indenting your code will also help).

Comment: What does the *error* say? There is a Syntax Error and, when that is corrected, there will be a run-time error. Follow through with debugging - make sure to use the tools/diagnoses methods available.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the element by ID, but you've only given it a name.

You'll therefore be getting an error when you try to access `element.value` because element is `null`.

The preferred fix is to give the `input` both a `name` *and* an `id`, usually both the same.

You've also missed out a trailing parenthesis on the `if` line.

*Both* of these errors would have appeared on your browser's JavaScript console, if you had looked.  You'd need to fix the latter before the first would appear, though.

Comment: actually it's after (in the file) although this will indeed be the first error that comes up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get an element by its ID, then it should have an id.

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
```

By the way, if you're trying to validate a form before submitting, you must stop the event propagation.

Comment: Right, didn't spot it right away. Should we keep john guessing? ;)

Comment: yes that for the help so far. i added id ="firstName" and it still will not work

Comment: @john: You're missing a closing parenthesis in the first `if` condition. I'd recommend to use a halfway decent editor as well as proper JS debugging tools, like the developer consoles of FF and/or Chrome. This will save you a bunch of time in situations like this one.